# Uploading theme larger than 2MB

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

### WordPress/Azure

I have edited my php.ini and changed upload_max_filesize from 2MB to 64MB successfully. Here you can see my phpinfo() results: http://www.lurkingpixels.com/wp-admin/info.php

I also wrote another script to verify that the values have changed indeed: http://www.lurkingpixels.com/wp-admin/info2.php

Yet, when i visit my wordpress panel and try to upload media, plugins or themes the same message keeps on popping up: "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."

My problem more specifically is that i want to upload a theme larger than 2mb, i have tried other workarounds like uploading the unziped theme directly to my wordpress content folder via FTP. However wordpress doesn't "see" my theme.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you also changed max post request?

Comment: You mean post_max_size? Then yes, its has been set at 64MB also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't see your theme means you need to check if style.css is there and if the theme files are unzipped properly. Usually when you upload theme using FTP, Wordpress takes it without issue. That's what my workaround has been with Upload Max limit issues.

However if you are unsuccessful with php.ini try creating a php.ini file with same code and upload it to wp-contents folder where your theme gets uploaded.

You can also try adding this on top of wp-config.php
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: I checked my theme, style.css is present indeed. The theme has been unzipped properly also. I tried the php.ini and wp-config.php but for some reason nothing happens. Thanks anyway!